# After transpilation of an ES6 module with webpack, module not exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have developed a small package available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/select-react-redux)

In the `src` version I have an export statement:

```
export class Select extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
         ...the component
        )
    }
}
```

When I use this component in this form, I can import it like so:

`import {Select} from 'select-react-redux';`

However, after I bundle the package with webpack to the `lib` directory, I get an output file, which I would expect to have the same content as the original file, but ES5 instead of ES6.

The bundled file contains:
`var Select = exports.Select = function (_React$Component) {}`
which means that the Select component should be available to me, but it isn't.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "the Select is not getting exported from it." --- please show what exactly it is transpiled to. (since it exports it just fine http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=export%20class%20Select%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3Efoo%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D )

Comment: The bundled version of the file is bundled and minimised, like here: https://github.com/adamgajzlerowicz/ReactSelect/blob/master/lib/index.js

Comment: Please provide only **relevant part not minified**.

Comment: In the bundled file I found this: 
var Select = exports.Select = function (_React$Component) {}
which means that it is getting exported... but why I can't import it?

Comment: Change your question correspondingly. It's not obvious what problem you have now.

Comment: So when you import - what exactly happens?

Answer (score 1):

In `package.json`, I see that your [package's entry point](https://github.com/adamgajzlerowicz/ReactSelect/blob/master/package.json#L12) is defined as:

```
"main": "src/index.js",
```

Since you've ES6 code in `src/index.js` you will need an appropriate loader to use the package as it is. But checking through your webpack configs I found that you already have transpiled code in `lib/index.js`. So you need to specify your packages entry point as:

```
"main": "lib/index.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

You export statements should be any of the following

```
export default class Select extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
         ...the component
        )
    }
}

//import 

import Select from 'select-react-redux'
```

or

```
class Select extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
             ...the component
            )
        }
    }

export {
   Select,
}

//import
import {Select} from 'select-react-redux'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. They are both correct but they didn't resolve the issue for me. I spent two days to trying to resolve the issue and I am certain that this is a webpack issue. Using the same source files but using babel to compile them modules are exported correctly.

`babel src/ -d lib/`

Also I went with export option like this, in the root of the `lib` folder in the `index.js` file. This way it will be more modular when I add more components

```
import {Select} from './Select';
export {Select as Select};
```